# Laravel Relationship tables passing extra "s" with id name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am getting "'lessons.subjects_id" while there is "subject_id" in lesson table. dont know where is problem in my relationship. My relationship models are as under:

```
    class Lessons extends Model
{
    public function subject()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Subjects');
    }

    public function category()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Category');
    }

}
```

Subject Model is:

```
    class Subjects extends Model
    {

       public function category()
       {
         return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Category');
       }
       public function Lessons()
       {
         return $this->hasMany('Lea\Lessons');
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because laravel auto-pluralizes table names, according to the plural version of the model(which is assumed to be in singular form by default), so your models being already pluralized is what the issue is.  This is in the [documentation(under table names)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent), as an aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't respect the Laravel convention you have to teach him about yours ;) by adding you foreign key name.

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) you have :

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the
>   model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to
>   have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention,
>   you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method:

```
class Lessons extends Model
{
    public function subject()
    {
           //                                  your foreign key
         return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Subjects', 'subject_id');
    }

    public function category()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Category');
    }

}
```

And

```
class Subjects extends Model
{

   public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('Lea\Category');
   }
   public function Lessons()
   {
     //                                  your foreign key
     return $this->hasMany('Lea\Lessons', 'subject_id');
   }
}
```

Comment: yes true, but that is my learning and i want to know where i missed laravel convention. although your solution is working with manual forgien key column name. but can you guide me where i missed convention?

Comment: Happy to help ;)